# Not responding error while typing a word document

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, freeze

I get "not responding" error while typing a word document, I guess it happens each time I press backspace to delete some letters. It's like it happens so and has happened many times till now, I chose "restart the program" from the three options it suggests.

Is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your pc is loaded with other tasks which consume the most part of resources and slow down Word. Try to look up for processes which take most of CPU.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that's the case, I have only chrome and word opened. Should I look up for those processes via Task manager?

Comment: Yes, or Process Explorer v15 from Sysinternals. Also there is possibility that HDD is busy performing operations for other processes and unable to respond immediately.